# it is possiable to override onleave of custom contol call to second time?

Tags: c#, winforms

First we need to override a custom control to make textbox text Titlecase on leave of that CaseingTxtBox and second time we use that leave event in a form to call some method. Is this possible?

We tried the code below for that but we get a call every time for `CaseingTxtBox`'s `Onleave` event but no call for `firstNameTextBox_Leave()`

I made a custom control that doed proper case for my textbox and that inherits from `TextBox` and we use the `Leave` event of the textbox to make the custom textbox's text title case.

```
public class CaseingTxtBox : TextBox
{  
    protected override void OnLeave(EventArgs e)
    {
        Text = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(Text.ToLower());
        //first call this event for make text titlecase
    }
}
```

We use that `CaseingTxtBox` control in my form to make text proper case and that works very well. We also use `Leave` event of that control to call a method but that method is not called.

```
this.firstNameTextBox.Leave += new System.EventHandl(this.firstNameTextBox_Leave);

 private void firstNameTextBox_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("hello");
    //second time call this event for call some method or propmt   messagebox onleave of CaseingTxtBox .
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overriding the method, but you are not calling `base.OnLeave(e)` in your handler so the events are never triggered.

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onleave%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is quite clear about this:

> **Notes to Inheritors:**
>   When overriding OnLeave in a derived class, be sure to call the base class's OnLeave method so that registered delegates receive the event.

So you need to override the method like this

```
protected override void OnLeave(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLeave(e);

    Text = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(Text.ToLower());
}
```

This will cause both your overridden `OnLeave` method and any possible events connected to `Leave` get called.